# Can pgAdmin's Query Tool Generate Clickable Links In My Table?

Tags: html, postgresql, pgadmin

A funny thing I realized in pgAdmin 4, the Query Tool can parse some HTML tags in its Data Output window.

For instance:

```sql
SELECT '<b>Funny Thing</b>', 'Less Funny Thing'
```

Will display the following:
[image]
Per se, that's pretty useless, but I wondered then if I could use an `<a href>` tag and generate clickable links that way. Now *that* would be useful. Sadly the `<a>` tag seems to not parse.

```sql
SELECT '<a href="https://www.postgresql.org/">Funny Thing</a>'
```

[image]

I realize it's a long shot, but does anybody know why and how I could get that `<a>` tag to work?

---

Sidenote: some other interesting tags work such as `<select>`. Again, pretty pointless, but funny.

[image]